# Improvement of the readOnly flag on Transactional annotation in Spring 5.1

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, readonly

reading about performance of the readOnly flag on the Spring Transactional annotation, its said that it has been an improvement from Spring version 5.1(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21494)

1. But it affects to Spring with JPA or Spring with Hibernate native?

Thanks

Comment: Both. It sets a specific hibernate property which will work for both.

Comment: It affects Spring with JPA when using the default hibernate as the provider, not other JPA providers. I'm not sure why, but Spring is still committing the transaction at the end, so it really is only a hibernate hint. Use with care.